# Flex web application works fine before compiling

Tags: apache-flex, compilation

I created a component in Flex which auto completes a couple of text inputs when users are typing an entry.  When running the application from Flex, everything works fine.  However, after I have compiled the application and load it, the auto complete does not work.  Here is some background information.

- Created in Adobe Flash Builder 4.5.
- Web Application is running on an internal network.
- The service which the auto complete uses is an external service.
- The internal server which hosts the web application can load the URL of the external service just fine.

I am not sure if it this is a permissions issue or what.  Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: "When running the application from Flex" I'm not sure what this means.  It is impossible to test an application without compiling it. You mean you it works fine when launching the application from Flash Builder; but not when you put it on a web server?  Or do you mean something else?  If you're using an external service for the AutoComplete data; do you have a cross domain file in place which would allow Flex to call the remote service when served off a different web server?  Loading the compiled SWF in a browser using a 'hard drive URL' will bypass cross domain security restrictions.

Comment: Excuse me for not being clear. Yes, I should have said when launching the web application from Flex everything works fine.  I do have a cross domain file which is setup to allow access from any request header and any domain.

Comment: Do you get any error messages or just nothing at all? What is de response of the server? Perhaps you could use a proxy like [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) to see what the response is (or maybe FireBug's 'net' panel can already do the trick).

Comment: No error messages.  Using Fiddler2 there is communication the the cross domain file and no reports of errors.  I am starting to wonder if I need to edit the cross domain file...

Comment: If the error is with your crossdomain file there should be an error returned by the server. Either the file itself can't be found and the server will return a 404, or it isn't configured correctly in which case you should get a security error. Are you listening for error events when calling the server?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems with receiving data from a web service. If the crossdomain file is not where it is supposed to be (webservice.domain.com/crossdomain.xml), you will receive a 404 error. So it does not sound like that is your issue.  If your crossdomain file does not contain the right tags, however, it won't throw an HTTP error, but it still won't work either.

It won't work properly by default if you are going from an HTTP server (where your application resides) to an HTTPS server (where your service is). This is typically bad security practice, but if you decide that it is OK, you can use the secure="false" for the allow-access-from tag.

Also, you may need to include both the allow-access-from tag and the allow-http-request-headers-from tag to get the data you are looking for.

Here is the crossdomain policy file specification by Adobe and it is a good resource in figuring out what attributes are required for each tag: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/articles/crossdomain_policy_file_spec.html.

Good luck!